# Why just dropdown not working on boostrap when i include vite vue js in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-5

i'm using laravel with vue and bootstrap 5, everything is fine just the dropdown from navbar menu doesn't work when i include vite in head `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

I don't know how to fix this if you have any ideea.. is a new project with all new staff..

e.g of dropdwon

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-rounded dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">Projects <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down ms-2"></i></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Users</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-transparent" placeholder="Search.."
                            aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                        <span class="mdi mdi-magnify"></span>
                    </div>
```

Thanks for your help,
Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In finally i solved this problem. Make sure the bootstrap are imported just once. Was imported in app.js and in my layout.

Comment: thanks for the solution! wasting a lot of my time too to figure out what went wrong until I found this.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think that's the problem.

Created a file from a template thrice and it went all well and good until I inserted `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` as I normally would. Took me a minute to realize that was what triggered it, as Bootstrap wasn't even included in my `resources/js/app.js` file.

What did it for me is to only just include `@vite(['resources/js/app.js'])` i my layout.

Here's to hoping this helps out a lot of people.